# JSON.parse() equivalent in mongo driver 3.x for Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongodb-java

`JSON.parse()` from mongo (Java driver) returns either a BasicDBList or a BasicDBObject.

However, when migrating to mongo driver 3.x, what's the new parse method that returns either `Document` or `List<Document>`?

In the new driver, `Document.parse()` only parses an object, not an array (throws an exception when given an array).

What is the equivalent of JSON.parse() for Arrays with 3.x Java drivers ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you get any clean solution to this?

Answer (score 13):

A simple trick to parse any JSON and to get either `Document` or `List<Document>`:

```
Document.parse("{\"json\":" + json + "}").get("json")
```

Answer (score 4):

To parse JSON string data using the **mongodb java driver 3.x**:

### Parse JSON document:

Use the `Document.parse()` static method to parse a single JSON document.

```
Document doc = Document.parse("{\"objA\":{\"foo\":1}}");
```

### Parse JSON array:

Use an instance of `BsonArrayCodec` to decode a `JsonReader`.

For example:

```
final String JSON_DATA
    = "[{\"objA\":{\"foo\":1}},"
    + "{\"objB\":{\"bar\":2}}]";

final CodecRegistry codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromProviders(asList(new ValueCodecProvider(),
    new BsonValueCodecProvider(),
    new DocumentCodecProvider()));

JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(JSON_DATA);
BsonArrayCodec arrayReader = new BsonArrayCodec(codecRegistry);

BsonArray docArray = arrayReader.decode(reader, DecoderContext.builder().build());

for (BsonValue doc : docArray.getValues()) {
    System.out.println(doc);
}
```

ref: http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.2/org/bson/json/JsonReader.html, 
http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.2/org/bson/codecs/BsonArrayCodec.html

Comment: Why not to just use BsonArray.parse then?

Answer (score 1):

Added cast to @Oleg Nitz answer, for completeness.

```
Object object = Document.parse("{\"json\":" + jsonData.getJson() + "}").get("json");

if (object instanceof ArrayList) {
    documents = (ArrayList<Document>) object;
} else (object instanceof Document) {
    document = (Document) object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Document doc = new Document("array", JSON.parse("[ 100, 500, 300, 200, 400 ]", new JSONCallback()));
System.out.println(doc.toJson()); //prints { "array" : [100, 500, 300, 200, 400] }
```

Comment: If you do a doc.get("array"), it'll return a BasicDBList, instead of a List :(

Comment: True, but it is subclass of `ArrayList`. So you could do this:

`new Document("array", new ArrayList((List)JSON.parse("[ 100, 500, 300, 200, 400 ]", new JSONCallback())));`

or use toMap():

`BasicDBList bDBl1 = (BasicDBList) JSON.parse("[ 100, 500, 300, 200, 400 ]", new JSONCallback());
new Document("array", bDBl1.toMap());`

Comment: It is possible we are missing something as this is not very clean

Comment: That wouldn't work either because, if my array consisted of documents, it would be parsed as BasicDBObject, and not a Document.

Comment: I agree, we're missing something crucial here.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that there's no easy equivalent.

If you use line-delimited JSON documents instead of a JSON array, it becomes fairly straightforward:

```
List<Document> getDocumentsFromLineDelimitedJson(final String lineDelimitedJson) {
    BufferedReader stringReader = new BufferedReader(
          new StringReader(lineDelimitedJson));
    List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
    String json;
    try {
        while ((json = stringReader.readLine()) != null) {
            documents.add(Document.parse(json));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ignore, can't happen with a StringReader
    }
    return documents;
}
```

For example, this call

```
System.out.println(getDocumentsFromLineDelimitedJson("{a : 1}\n{a : 2}\n{a : 3}"));
```

will print:

> [Document{{a=1}}, Document{{a=2}}, Document{{a=3}}]

Comment: This is rarely the case though, isn't it?

Comment: It depends.  This is the format output by [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) by default, for example.  And there are several standardization efforts: [JSON lines](http://jsonlines.org/) and [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/)

Comment: I was referring to line separated JSON. Mostly, you've got objects in an array, which is the value to another key in another object altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest equivalent for me is to use any json library to convert the json to POJO. Below is an example using jackson:

```
String input = "[{\"objA\":{\"foo\":1}},{\"objB\":{\"bar\":2}}]";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Document> output = (List<Document>) mapper.readValue(input, List.class)
            .stream().map(listItem -> new Document((LinkedHashMap)listItem))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This doesn't handle nested objects, a map inside of your top level map.